# How to implement a 'Vote up' System for posts in my blog?

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine, jinja2

I have written a simple blog using Python in google app engine. I want to implement a voting system for each of my posts. My posts are stored in a SQL database and I have a column for no of votes received. Can somebody help me set up voting buttons for individual posts? I am using Jinja2 as the templating engine.

How can I make the voting secure? I was thinking of sending a POST/GET when someone clicks on the vote button which my python script will then read and update the database accordingly. But then I realized that this was insecure. All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The concern being that visitors can vote N times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, keep in mind that there is no such thing as "secure", just "secure enough for X". There's always a tradeoff—more secure means more annoying for your legitimate users and more expensive for you.

Getting past these generalities, think about your specific case. There is nothing that has a 1-to-1 relationship with users. IP addresses or computers are often shared by multiple people, and at the same time, people often have multiple addresses or computers. Sometimes, something like this is "good enough", but from your question, it doesn't sound like it would be.

However, with user accounts, the only false negatives come from people intentionally creating multiple accounts or hacking others' accounts, and there are no false positives. And there's a pretty linear curve in the annoyance/cost vs. security tradeoff, all the way from ""Please don't create sock puppets" to CAPTCHA to credit card checks to web of trust/reputation score to asking for real-life info and hiring an investigator to check it out.

In real life, there's often a tradeoff between *more* than just these two things. For example, if you're willing to accept more cheating if it directly means more money for you, you can just charge people real money to vote (as with those 1-900 lines that many TV shows use).

---

> How do Reddit and Digg check multiple voting from a single registered user?

I don't know exactly how Reddit or Digg does things, but the general idea is simple: Keep track of individual votes.

Normally, you've got your users stored in a SQL RDBMS of some kind. So, you just add a `Votes` table with columns for user ID, question ID, and answer. (If you're using some kind of NoSQL solution, it should be easy to translate appropriately. For example, maybe there's a document for each question, and the document is a dictionary mapping user IDs to answers.) When a user votes, just `INSERT` a row into the database.

When putting together the voting interface, whether via server-side template or client-side AJAX, call a function that checks for an existing vote. If there is one, instead of showing the vote controls, show some representation of "You already voted Yes." You also want to check again at vote-recording time, to make sure someone doesn't hack the system by opening 200 copies of the page, all of which allow voting (because the user hasn't voted yet), and then submitting 200 Yes votes, but with a SQL database, this is as simple as making `Question, User` into a multi-column unique key.

If you want to allow vote changing or undoing, just add more controls to the interface, and handle them with `UPDATE` and `DELETE` calls. If you want to get really fancy—like this site, which allows undoing if you have enough rep and if either your original vote was in the past 5 minutes or the answer has been edited since your vote (or something like that)—you may have to keep some extra info, like record a row for each voting action, with a timestamp, instead of just a single answer for each user.

This design also means that, instead of keeping a count somewhere, you generate the vote tally on the fly by, e.g., `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Votes WHERE Question=? GROUP BY Answer`. But, as usual, if this is too slow, you can always optimize-by-denormalizing and keep the totals along with the actual votes. Similarly, if your user base is huge, you may want to archive votes on old questions and get them out of the operational database. And so on.

Comment: How do Reddit and Digg check multiple voting from a single registered user?

Comment: @VaishakVKumar: Let me edit the answer, because it may be too long to explain in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If voting is only for subscribed users, then enable voting after members log in to your site. 
If not, then you can track users' IP addresses so one IP address can vote once for a single article in a day.

By the way, what kind of security do you need?

Comment: Using the IP to limit votes is easier but it does not work for when there are multiple users coming from the same IP such as from a university.

Comment: The voters will be registered users.